# android jni file stdbool.h not found

Tags: android, android-ndk

I create a default jni project, the include <stdbool.h> fail.

I search the sdk path, the stdbool.h is there:

```
./25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/stdbool.h
./25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/14.0.6/include/stdbool.h
./25.1.8937393/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdbool.h
```

How should I config it to find this header file?